# typo3 Uncaught Error: Class not found when start development new extension typo3 v 10

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

Hello Typo3 experts I trying to build an extension in typo3 I have an HTML page that uses jquery to call a class called rpc.php when I tried to use any function from typo3 core it always give me class not found

```
namespace GlobalizationPartnersInternational\Gpi\Models\Tsc;

class rpc{

    public $endPoint = '';
    public $token = '';

    public function main(){
        $typo3InstallDir = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Environment::getPublicPath() . '/';
        print_r('Hello World!'.$typo3InstallDir,true);
    }

}

$rpc = new rpc();
$rpc->main();
```

JQUERY CODE

```
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if (window.efx && window.efx.init) {
               efx.startup("http://localhost/typo3/typo3conf/ext/gpi/Classes/models/tsc/rpc.php");
                efx.init();
            }
            $(document).on("keyup", "#tsc_SearchQuery", function() {
                $("li label span, li label").css("background-color", "");
                var phrase = this.value;
                if (phrase.length < MIN_QUERY) {
                    return false;
                }
                //find text to highlight
                $("li label span, li label").each(function(i, v) {
                    var block = $(v);
                    $(v).filter(function() {
                        return block.text().match(new RegExp(phrase, "gi"));
                    }).css("background-color", COLOR_HIGHLIGHT);
                });
                return false;
            });

        });
    })(jQuery);
```

**Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Environment' not found in C:\wamp64\www\typo3\typo3conf\ext\gpi\Classes\models\tsc\rpc.php

*I appreciated any help thanks in advance*

Comment: Flush TYPO3 cache and class autoload from install tool wizard under Admin Tool->Maintenance. Also, here is detailed explanation for Extension development https://stackoverflow.com/a/66310429/5961782

Answer (score 0):

You can't just call a class like `http://localhost/typo3/typo3conf/ext/gpi/Classes/models/tsc/rpc.php`

If you are using TYPO3 11 I suggest to write a custom [middleware](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestHandling/Index.html) or if you use an older TYPO3 version a bit simpler variant is to use but already marked as deprecated!

As written in the [example](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestHandling/Index.html#returning-a-custom-response) you need:

1. Register the middleware in your extension in `Configuration/RequestMiddlewares.php`
2. Implement the middlware and return the response you need

Comment: Georg, there is missing *what* to use...

Comment: what is missing ?? and also I'm using typo3 latest version of 10 if I try to use 
$rpc = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(rpc::class);
$rpc->main();
________________________________
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility' not found

Comment: I updated the answer. there is no shortcut. you need a custom middleware

Comment: thanks a lot Georg, let me try and back to you I appreciated your effort